# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) at line file_data = json.loads(file_s)

Tags: python, json, file, load

Hey everyone so I am trying to load a bunch of json files into my program but whenever I try to run this code:

```
import json
import os
import sys
import requests

path = r'C:\Users\'
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]
print(json_files)
JsonDictionary = {}

struct = {}


try:
    for x in range(len(json_files)):
        Jpath = str(path +'\\'+ json_files[x])
        file = open(Jpath)
        file_s = file.read()
        print("File Read: " + str(file_s))
        file_data = json.loads(file_s) 
    print(Jpath)
    JsonDictionary = json.load(Jpath)

except IOError as e:
    print (e)
    print ('IOError: Unable to open json file. Terminating execution.')
    exit(1)

print (JsonDictionary)
```

Here is the error output:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-0333b738997d> in <module>
     24 #          print (sys.exc_info())
     25         print("File Read: " + str(file_s))
---> 26         file_data = json.loads(file_s)
     27     print(Jpath)
     28     JsonDictionary = json.load(Jpath)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorkeras2\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    355     if cls is None:
    356         cls = JSONDecoder

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorkeras2\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorkeras2\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

All I get is JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).
I've seen other solutions presented for the same error code however none of them seem to be the solution. Is it a code problem or an input problem?

Comment: Code looks good, maybe you've got an empty `json` file?

Comment: @Cartucho I've rechecked all files and none of them appear to be empty. I checked the formating as well and all seems json valid

Comment: I think the problem is with `json.load(Jpath)`, given that `Jpath` is a `str` but `json.load` expects a file-like object - https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-file-like-object. By the way, why you have both `json.loads(file_s) ` and `json.load(Jpath)`?

Comment: @Cartucho even if I remove that line completely I have the same problem. Still on the other line, the file_data = json.loads(file_s) line. In all honesty, my goal is to load all of the json files data into a dictionary so that I can analyse them by category afterwards.
Even if I remove the string from the parameter, it gives me the same result

Comment: I think you should write the complete error output, that way will be easier to help you.

Comment: @Cartucho already edited it in. Thank u so much for taking the time to help me

Comment: What is the output of `print(file_s)` just before the error occurs?

Comment: @snakecharmerb it prints out all of the files' names. Not putting it in since there are over 200 files

Answer (score 0):

Check if your file has **BOM**.
Right click on the file > Properties > Size.  (example: **859** bytes)
Open it with Notepad++ and change the *Encoding* (topbar menu).
If "UTF-8-BOM" is selected it is a file with BOM. Otherwise the problem is another one.
Change it to "UTF-8" and save.
Check the size again, it should be 3 bytes less. (example: **856** bytes).

Now, if this solve the problem you can just use the original file(s), just adding the encoding "utf-8-sig" (instead of the default "utf-8"). It will take care of the the BOM (if it exists, no need to check).

You can use:

```py
open("", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig") # utf-8-sig takes care of BOM
```